# Is there a way to define the props of a custom object in a separate file in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import, export

Suppose I have a  custom CoolButton object that accepts props like width={20} height={50} and backgroundColor={"#fff"}. Is there a way I could put all the props in a different file and then  invoke these props with a single name?

So for example:

props.js

```
allProps = {
    width={20}, 
    height={50}, 
    backgroundColor={"#fff"}
}
```

app.js

```
<CoolButton allProps><Text>Button Text</Text></CoolButton>
```

Comment: `<CoolButton {...allProps}><Text>Button Text</Text></CoolButton>` You can firstly export props and import props in app and then spread it like this.

Comment: Create a valid object literal: `allProps = {
    width: 20, 
    height: 50, 
    backgroundColor: "#fff" 
}` and spread it: `<CoolButton {...allProps}>`

Comment: Doing that gives me: "import must be from a react component".